# how to find number of rows which satisfy different conditions on two numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let says we have two numpy array as `a = [4, 5, 8, 10, 4, 8, 4]`
and `b = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`.
we have to find number of rows in which first array element is 4 and second array element is 1.

4,1 
 5,0 
 8,1 
 10,1 
 4,1 
 8,0 
 4,0

In this it is 2.since there are two rows in which first element is 4 and second is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like

```py
np.sum((a == 4) & (b == 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the basics of python:-

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([4, 5, 8, 10, 4, 8, 4])
b = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
new_pair = []
for a_value, b_value in zip(a,b):
    if a_value==4 and b_value==1:
        new_pair.append([a_value,b_value])
print( len(new_pair) )
```

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's like filtering your lists into the pairing within the same list.

Have you tried `isin()` method in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'List_1': a, 'List_2':b})

df_list = [] 

for i in range(0,len(a)):
    df = df.loc[df['List_1'].isin([a[i]])]
    df = df.loc[df['List_2'].isin([b[i]])]
    df_list.append(df)

#your df_list will now have the values as you need
```

Hope this helps :))